# ASP.Net Checking if a remote file exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, web-applications

I have a ASP.Net website with links to files stored on a file server.  These files are modified constantly and so the links will not always be valid, this includes changes to permissions, files being moved or deleted, etc.  I implemented a method in the code-behind to check the validity of these links as they are constructed, if it fails the code will add CSS to change the color of link:

**Check URL**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if a URL exists. Method by http://www.vcskicks.com/check-website.php
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">URL to validate</param>
    /// <returns>True if the URL was resolved, false otherwise</returns>
    private static bool validURL(string url)
        {
            Uri urlCheck = new Uri(url);
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(urlCheck);
            request.Timeout = 5000;//Timeout set to 5 seconds

            WebResponse response;
            try
            {
                response = request.GetResponse();
                if (request.RequestUri != response.ResponseUri)
                    return false;

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.Message.Contains("denied"))
                    return true; //url exists but access is denied
                else
                    return false; //url does not exist
            }

}
```

**Calling the above method**

```
link.NavigateUrl = "file://" + serverLocation;
                        //MODIFICATION 3/21/11 - change link to DarkRed if it is not valid
                        if (!validURL(link.NavigateUrl))
                        {
                            link.Attributes.Add("style", "color: DarkRed");
                        }
```

My problem is that not all the invalid links are getting the style added to them.  The strange thing is that when I step through the method in debug mode using one of the bad links that was not colored, the method will return false and color the link as expected.  There's a lot more involved then what I present above, but I searched the entire aspx code-behind for any other locations where the link url is being set and couldn't find any.  I don't know if there's some post processing going on that somehow clears any styles that were applied to some of the links.  The fact that some links are colored while others are not is very confusing to me.  Has anyone else encountered similar behavior before?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new DataAnnotations in ASP.NET MVC 3.

http://kitsula.com/Article/ASP-NET-MVC-3-JQuery-validation-Data-Annotation-Unobtrusive-Client-Validation

[ASP.Net Checking if a remote file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424414/asp-net-checking-if-a-remote-file-exists)